# There is no entry in the $TCA array for the table "index_stat_word". TYPO3, v.11.5. Indexed search

Tags: typo3, tx-indexed-search

I need a help please.
TYPO3 v.11.5. I'd like to get data from table index_stat_word (indexed_search):

```
page {
    10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
    10 {
        dataProcessing {         
            20 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
            20 {
                table = index_stat_word
                select {
                    selectFields = word, COUNT(word) AS word_count
                    groupBy = word
                    orderBy = word_count DESC
                    max = 4
                }  
                as = mostPopularWords
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have an error:

`There is no entry in the $TCA array for the table "index_stat_word". This means that the function enableFields() is called with an invalid table name as argument.`

The table "index_stat_word" is present and complete.

Thank you for the answers.

Comment: It should be easy to define the appropriate TCA. TCA can be defined in any extension. indexed_search seems to use another way of writing to the table, so it does not need this TCA.

Comment: Please don't define it in TCA. These tables are not TCA managed for good. Adding them to TCA control will add additional fields to them. The point here is to create a custom DataProcessor and doing the query direckty with QueryBuilder and avoid the conversion step and leveraging TCA.

Comment: Now I have an error: "InvalidFieldNameException: An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM `index_stat_word` WHERE `index_stat_word`.`pid`."
But the table doesn't have the "pid" field.